# How to properly name or label pictures in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, images, org-ref

In particular I can't understand the purpose of `fig:`. Is it to distinguish
figures from other blocks e.g. `#+NAME code:python_foo`? Does it alter org modes behaviour or is it a
convention?

I've seen the the last one `label:` used on [John Kitchin's examples](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/03/08/Using-yasnippet-to-get-completion-in-ref-links/). Considering his expertise on that topic, `label:`
implies to provide some magic superior to `#+NAME`?

```
#+NAME:   my_image
#+NAME:   fig:my_image
label:my_image
```

Comment: Convention. There may be extensions that make use of `fig:` or `code:` but standard Org mode does not (AFAIK is always implied). I have no idea what John Kitchin's `label:` does or how it works, but I'm sure he'll be around at some point to enlighten us :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is convenient to use a prefix like `fig:` in a name when you use something like org-ref that uses completion to insert references using all the "labels" in the document to the thing you named. In a long document you may have figures, tables, src blocks and sections, and using a prefix like fig:, tab:, src:, sec:, etc. makes it easy to narrow down to the kind of thing you are referencing.

In LaTeX, (and org-ref for other backends https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/blob/master/org-ref-refproc.el), there is something called cleveref that can use those prefixes to automatically prefix the cross-reference with text, e.g. cleveref:fig-one  -> Figure 1 on export.

The `label:` thing is different, that is an org-ref link for a label (in latex, it translates to \label{some-thing}. It is like the #+name, but you can put it in other places, e.g. in a heading, or in a caption, even in a paragraph. Usually, you use one or the other. Lately, I favor #+name where possible, and radio targets on headings instead of label links. These are standard org features.